# How to show marker content by default without any mouse event?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have written the following code:

```
for (var i=1; i < latitude.length; i++) {
    var markerCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude[i],longitude[i]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerCenter,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
    marker.setVisible(visible)
    markers.push(marker);
    addInfoWindow(marker,Location[i]);
}

function addInfoWindow(marker, message) {

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: message
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

When the user selects or unselects a check-box corresponding marker will be set visible according to his action.

```
function markerVisibility(check_box,lat,lon) {
    var index;

    for (var i = 1; i < latitude.length; i++) {
        if (latitude[i] == lat && longitude[i] == lon) {
            index=i-1;
            break;
        }
    }

   //User selects the check box to see the marker in Google Map
   if (check_box.checked) {
       markers[index].setVisible(true)
        markers[index].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE); 
   }
    //User unselects the checkbox not to see the marker
   else {
        markers[index].setVisible(false)
   }
}
```

Code is working fine. With this code I have to click the marker to see the content. But I need to load the marker content by default when it loads the map and points a marker (without any clicking or hovering).

Another thing, if we set the marker is set to visibility "false" still, it's showing the marker content. How to set it's visibility off?
Please give a suggestion in `JavaScript`.

Comment: Can you put your code on-line (Codepen, fiddle ect.)

Comment: _"when it loads the map and points a marker"_ - what do you mean by 'points a marker'?

Comment: that means when the page loads the map i.e intialize the map and it shows a marker based on the latitude & longitude then i need to show the marker content without any mouse event @duncan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the event listener for the infowindow, and just open it as soon as you create it.

```
function addInfoWindow(marker, message) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: message
    });

    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

Also if you then want to show/hide that infowindow when the marker's visibility is toggled, you could do something like the following:

```
function addInfoWindow(marker, message) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: message
    });

    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

    marker.infowindow = infoWindow;
}

function markerVisibility(check_box,lat,lon) {
    ...

   if (check_box.checked) {
       markers[index].setVisible(true);
       marker.infowindow.open(map, marker);
   }
   else {
        markers[index].setVisible(false);
        marker.infowindow.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: yeah it's working but how to show/hide the marker content when calling this function- `markerVisibility` ?

Comment: Your Code is working fine but I had to modify this line.
`marker.infowindow.open();`
as
`marker.infowindow.open(map, marker);`

Comment: @AnuragChakraborty ah yes, I've updated my answer to include that